# How do i show value that meets specific criteria in wolfram mathematica?

Tags: loops, if-statement, wolfram-mathematica

i will try to explain my problem 
Lets say i have data like this `x={1,2,3,4,5,6}`  and my condition is `4<=x<=6` and I want to show that the value that meets criteria is `5`. 
my program looks like this

`k = 0;`

`Do[If[4 <= x[[i]] <= 6, k = k + 1], {i, 1, Length[data]}];`

`Print["amount of numbers that meets criteria  ", k]`

And my problem is that I don't know how to continue to show the Value of number that meets criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to choose items that satisfy a condition then Select is often useful. If you want to know how many items satisfied the criteria then Length is often useful.

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Length[Select[x, 4<=#<=6&]]
```

gives you 3. That # and & notation is defining a function that has no name but that you can still use. You can get some information about how to use that by looking up Function in the help pages.